# Comment prononcer les terminaisons archaiques « -oit » ?

Tags: prononciation, histoire, conjugaison, ancien-français

Comment prononce-t-on des mots comme *pourroit* au lieu de *pourrait* ?

Je vous prie de comparer avec des mots français contemporains ou d'utiliser [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_conventions_of_the_International_Phonetic_Alphabet).

J'ajoute que j'ai rencontré ces formes dans des chansons (par exemple : [Dieu, qu'il l'a fait…](http://poetesvospdf.hebergratuit.com/orleans_charles_ballades_et_rondeaux.pdf)).

Comment: Juste par curiosité: à quelles chansons fais-tu référence?? "Dieu, qui l'a fait" + "pourroit" ne me donne aucun résultat probant sur Google...

Comment: Il y a eu une erreur dans mon texte, tu le trouves par exemple ici :  http://poetesvospdf.hebergratuit.com/orleans_charles_ballades_et_rondeaux.pdf

Answer (score 18, accepted):

J'imagine que la question porte sur la prononciation *archaïque* (ou plus exactement, en Ancien Français) de ces mots, et non pas la prononciation contemporaine (qui serait tout simplement la même que les autres mots en 'oi', à savoir [wa]).

La prononciation de la diphtongue 'oi' a beaucoup évolué entre le français médiéval et nos jours (et évidemment, il faut aussi prendre en compte les variations entre dialectes).

Initialement, on prononçait les deux voyelles séparément (comme dans 'boy' en anglais). Assez rapidement, elle est passé à 'oué'/'oé' [ue]/[we]. Par exemple, le mot "roi", au XVè siècle, se prononçait à peu près: `roué` [rwe].
La lecture en [wa] pour la diphtongue 'oi' s'est imposé après la Révolution, au cours du XIXè siècle. À la même époque, la plupart des formes "archaïques" ont disparues (remplacement de 'ois'/'oit' par 'ais'/'ait' qui est alors passé de [we] à [e]).

Je ne suis pas sûr de la prononciation de 'oi' à l'intérieur d'une forme conjuguée (en particulier la question de la consonne finale, qui se prononçait à une époque, avant de devenir progressivement muette), mais il est très probable qu'un mot comme 'pourroit', à l'époque où il était encore en usage, se serait prononcé `pourroué` ou `pourrouét'` (son [we]).

*Note: je m'excuse en avance pour les approximations sur les prononciations en IPA: ça n'a jamais été mon fort.*

Comment: +1, à noter que des prononciations proches du [ue]/[we] sont encore rencontrées en Wallonie, dans certaines provinces francophones du Canada et en Normandie.

Comment: @Alain: intéressant... Je sais que certains coins un peu rustiques de Québec/Acadie (où le parler est à cheval entre français et joual) ont une forte tendance à prononcer des mots tels que "toi"/"moi" comme "toué"/"moué"... Je n'avais jamais entendu d'accent similaire en Europe francophone.

Comment: En ce qui concerne la Normandie vous pouvez vous intéresser aux différents ouvrages sur le patois normand.  J’en possède sur papier mais on trouve aussi des références en accès libre ou partiel sur Google books qui ont de plus le mérite de l’ancienneté.  ...

Comment: ... On peut lire par exemple « _oi_ se prononce _ai_ ou _ei_ presque partout dans l’arrondissement de Pont-Audemer. EXEMPLES : _mai, tai, sai_ au lieu de _moi, toi, soi_ ; – _drait, endrait_ pour _droit_ et _endroit_ ; - _craire, baire_ pour _croire_ et _boire_ […] il ya des localités [Berville sur Mer] où la prononciation d’_oi_ n’est pas _ai_ mais _oué_, _crouére_ et _bouére_ pour _croire_ et _boire_ […] _moué, toué, soué_ pour _moi, toi soi_ ... »  Tout cela n'est pas très étonnant quand on connait l'importance de la Normandie dans l'émigration vers la *Belle Province*.

Answer (score 6):

Les diphthongues « oi » et dérivées (« ois », « oit ») se prononcent toutes [wa]. Le « t » ou le « s » finals sont muets.

On prononcera donc « pourroit » : [purwa].

À noter que cette forme archaïque de la conjugaison du verbe « pouvoir » n’est plus du tout usitée en français moderne, et est remplacée par « pourrait ».

Comment: Bien que courante, la prononciation de formes tels que "pourroit" comme [purwa] est anachronique: ces formes ayant disparues avant que leur prononciation n'évolue, il n'y a aucune raison d'utiliser une lecture contemporaine (si ce n'est un instinct de vouloir "faire ancien"). Un équivalent très courant en anglais, serait la prononciation erronée du '[þ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter))' (dans des expressions comme "[ye olde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye_Olde)...") comme un 'y' alors qu'il s'agit d'un son très similaire à 'th'...

Answer (score 1):

Avant la réforme de l'orthographe dans la troisième décennie du XIXe siècle, on écrivait pourroit, mais on disait pourrè. En ancien français, les diphthongues oi/ai/ei étaient interchangeables et variaient selon la région et le dialecte. On aurait pu tout aussi bien dire pourroé que pourréi ou pourraï (écoute un Québécois dire le mot seize ou haleine pour t'en faire une idée).

Or, déjà au 12e siècle, la prononciation monophthongale è était consacrée avant le t et le s final. Cette prononciation peut se voir dans les mots de l'ancien français qui ont été adoptés en anglais: on dit *feat* et *peace*, pas *faite* et *paice*.

En résumé, la chose la plus simple serait de prononcer le oi comme un è dans les terminaisons verbales, et comme un oé ailleurs (avec l'exception peut-être du mot "oir" que je prononcerais ère).

Un autre chose à ne pas oublier est que le r final des infinitifs du premier groupe se prononce en ancien français. Donc un mot comme blâmer rime avec mer. On devrait dire blâmère. De même avec les noms finissant avec -er ou -ier: c'est chevalière et non chevalié (chevalier).