# Was there a shift in pronunciation?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, histoire

I've been slowly reading one of Robespierre's reports in French, and I've noticed some spellings that are now unused. For example:

> on seroit tenté . . .
>
> si le destin m'avoit fait naître dans une contrée étrangère et lointaine, j'aurois adressé au ciel des vœux continuels pour ta prospérité

In all of these cases OI is used where I would expect an AI, in the verb endings for the imperfect (or as such, the endings for the present conditional). Is this common in older texts? If so, is this indicative of older pronunciations, and when did the shift to the current spellings occur?

Keep in mind that I'm not a native speaker, so perhaps I just lack sufficient exposure.

Comment: See here: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/104/comment-prononcer-les-terminaisons-archaiques-oit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was indeed a shift in the pronunciation of "oi" in these words that long predates the [1835 reform](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9forme_de_l'orthographe_fran%C3%A7aise_de_1835) where "oi" was replaced by "ai" in them.

"Oi", now /wa/, used to be pronounced like "ouai" or "oué" /we/. The /we/ to /wa/ shift was gradual, initiated by the lower class people and considered to be inelegant by the aristocracy. It was generalized after the French revolution.

The old pronunciation is surviving in some regional accents, especially in Quebec.

Answer (score 5):

In the examples given, *seroit*, *avoit*, *aurois* were pronounced /sərɛ/, /avɛ/ and /orɛ/ in Robespierre's time and are not indicative of an older pronunciation.

The 1835 reform made official and sought to impose a change in spelling (*ai* instead of *oi*) that reflected a well-established difference in pronunciation.  Some writers had already used the *ai* spelling in their publications well before 1835.  The most famous one was Voltaire who as a matter of principle wanted spelling to reflect more faithfully actual pronunciation.

He wrote in a letter to Mme Denis, dated 18 January 1752 :   « Ce qu'on vous a dit contre l'orthographe du *Siècle de Louis XIV* ne me convertira pas.  Je suis toujours pour qu'on écrive comme on parle : cette méthode serait bien plus facile pour les étrangers. »  The *Siècle de Louis XIV* he is referring to had just been published by Henning in Berlin and Voltaire had seen to it that his printer replaced *oi* in imperfect and present conditional endings by *ai*.

Voltaire's position on orthography was so extreme that he was called a *néographe* in Diderot and D'Alembert's Encyclopédie :

NÉOGRAPHE. On nomme ainsi celui qui affecte une manière d’écrire nouvelle et contraire à l’orthographe reçue. L’orthographe ordinaire nous fait écrire *françois*, *anglois*, *j’étois*, *ils aimeroient*; M. de Voltaire écrit *français*, *anglais*, *j’étais*, *ils aimeraient*, en mettant *ai* pour *oi* dans ces exemples, et partout où l’*oi* est le signe d’un *e* ouvert. Nous employons des lettres majuscules à la tête de chaque phrase qui commence après un point, à la tête de chaque nom propre, etc.  M. de Voltaire avoit supprimé toutes ces capitales dans la premiere édition de son *Siècle de Louis XIV* publié sous le nom de M. de Francheville.

As to when *seroit* came to be pronounced /sərɛ/, Brunot and Bruneau in their *Précis historique de la langue française* say the following :

*Avois* /avwɛ/, etc. et *aurois* /orwɛ/, etc., se prononçaient à la Cour /avɛ/, /orɛ/ dès la fin du 16e siècle.  En 1695, Hindret rapporte que « quelques savants », « il y a environ vingt ans », voulurent faire revivre la diphtongue /wɛ/ des imparfaits, « quoiqu'il y eût déjà plus de trente ans qu'elle était hors d'usage dans ces terminaisons ».  Ils prononçaient la diphtongue « à pleine bouche », « pour donner, disaient-ils, une prononciation plus mâle et plus ferme à ces terminaisons ».  Mais cet usage « ne fut pas de durée ».  C'est donc vers 1650 que ces prononciations anciennes (/avwɛ/, /orwɛ/) ont disparu au barreau et dans le monde des prédicateurs, où elles s'étaient conservées plus longtemps.