# Existe-t-il une langue françoise ?

Tags: orthographe, histoire

Je suis en train de lire l'histoire de la Belgique. Je tombe sur un extrait contenant le terme ***la langue françoise***. L'extrait est le suivant :

*L’usage de la langue françoise est universel dans le Duché de Bouillon ; le
peuple y parle généralement le même patois, à peu près dans la ville
comme au village.*

> Daniel DROIXHE, Dialecte et français dans la Wallonie d’ancien régime, Une réponse
>   inédite à l’enquête de l’abbé Grégoire (1790), dans Hervé HASQUIN éd., Hommages à la
>   Wallonie, Mélanges offerts à Maurice A. Arnould et Pierre Ruelle, p. 144, Bruxelles,
>   Université libre de Bruxelles, 1981.

S'agit-il d'une erreur de frappe?

Comment: Quand on fait une citation il est préférable de dire d'où elle est extraite. On y fait visiblement référence à une époque précédent la dissolution du Duché de Bouillon(1796).

Comment: C'est fait, merci.

Comment: S’il ne disoit verité, il seroit gehainé. Aujourd'hui on écrirait : S'il ne disait pas la vérité, il serait torturé. La première phrase consiste, du coup, un exemple de l'écriture à la "françoise". Pas d'ancien français ; il s'agit d'ancienne orthographe (comme deux parmi les trois répondes déjà affirme). Au fait, beaucoup de mots en oi ont été transformés en ai lors de la réforme de l'orthographe de 1835. Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29263/quest-ce-que-disoit-et-seroit

Answer (score 9):

*Françoise* dans *langue françoise* est une orthographe ancienne qui s'est maintenue jusqu'au début du 19e siècle, plus précisément jusqu'à la réforme de 1835 ([https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Réforme_de_l%27orthographe_française_de_1835](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9forme_de_l%27orthographe_fran%C3%A7aise_de_1835)), après laquelle la graphie *français* au lieu de *françois* s'est rapidement imposée.

La citation remonte aux années 1790, il est donc tout à fait logique et conforme à l'usage du temps d'y trouver l'orthographe *langue françoise* et non pas *langue française*.

Answer (score 6):

Probablement il n’y a aucune erreur. Selon [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fran%C3%A7ais), jusqu’à 1798, on écrivait « françois » à la place de « français ». L’écriture de nombreux mots était changée ainsi pendant les 18ème et 19ème siècles: par exemple, [les terminaisons de l’imparfait](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13956/4082) contenaient anciennement le digraphe « oi » et non « ai ».