# "...Ne sauroient renfermer le tems..." translation

Tags: traduction, ancien-français

I'm trying to translate some portion of Lagrange's work "Analytical mechanic". Although I'm fully aware of the fact that I can simply find a translation in any library, I want to translate it by myself.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck with one sentence:

...*d'où il est facile de conclure que ces équations ne sauroient renfermer le tems t*.

I have translated the first part: *...From which it is easy to conclude that these equations...*, but I'm stuck with the last part.

I didn't find *sauroient* in Wiktionary but it seems to be the Old-French form of the future form for *savoir*, and *tems* seems to be Old-French for for *temps*, given the physcial meaning of the work, but still I can't give some sense to the sentence under these assumptions.

Comment: **oi** spelling in French verbs was modified in to **ai** French verbs  to coincide with the evolving pronunciation, it happened in the 15th century, it is *Classical French*. See [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/111/358).

Comment: Retranslations are excellent practice. You can also then compare with the existing one after for an "answer key" to check your work and hone your skills. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means:

> From which it is easy to conclude that these equations could not contain the time *t*

i.e. are independent of time.

- *sauroient* is indeed old for *sauraient* from *savoir*. (Maybe not real "[Old French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_French)" which is officially before 1,300. But yes, nobody uses that today anymore).
- *savoir* here is a literary usage which has the meaning of *pouvoir* by "semantic crossover". So, *ne savoir renfermer* means *ne pouvoir renfermer*, i.e. *cannot contain*. See II D in [CNRTL/savoir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/savoir), which gives the following expressions as examples: *.On ne saurait dire; on ne saurait en conclure, en déduire (qqc., que), en dire autant de; on n'en saurait douter; on ne saurait trop rappeler, insister sur, recommander (qqc.).*

Interesting to note that Lagrange was originally Italian, but wrote his Mécanique Analytique in Berlin, in French... (in 1788).

Comment: Lagrange was likely a native speaker of French. His grand-father was Parisian and his mother was also of French ascent. Everything he published was written in French (possibly in Latin too).

Comment: Not Old French indeed, *-oient* is written Classical French corrected to match pronunciation in [the 1835 reform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reforms_of_French_orthography#19th_century)