# Is there a reason to pronounce the word 'foi' in 'en bonne foi' in 16th century French differently, like 'fui/foui'?

Tags: prononciation, ancien-français

In the song Petite folle by Orlando di Lasso (Lassus) there is a phrase

> 'En bonne foi, vous êtes la plus duitte.'

On [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhV213570lk) I hear singers of a famous chamber choir pronounce the word 'foi' as 'fui' or 'foui'.

Why is that or is it simply a mistake?

Comment: I hear /fwɛ/ or /fuɛ/ which is the regular 16th century pronunciation. The /wa/ pronunciation of the  letters "oi" is recent. The letters "oi" were pronounced /we/  until about the 19th century or maybe later in some rural areas. I think it's still the case in Québec. French Language already has [a good answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/111/358) on this pronunciation.

Comment: Clear! Thank you very much!